# Basic Authentication Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication

I am building an app that uses an API, and also has the functionality to be a website with a log in, sign up etc. When I use a client server app like POSTman I want to use Basic Authentication, but the username and password for the authentication should be the user's username and password. When the User logs into the API, it should be able to see that specific User's posts. Is there anyway to make the app implement basic authentication using the User's username and password, instead of a concrete password for every user? I have been struggling to find anything on this matter. Any help and insight would be greatly appreciated, if any code needs to be seen I will be happy to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be achieved without Devise:

```
before_action :require_authentication
def require_authentication
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |u,p|
    user = User.find_by(username: u)
    true if user && user.authenticate(p)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have one question. When i use this authentication it works, but it only authenticates once. And it doesn't authenticate a none signed in user? Any suggestions? @mysmallidea

Comment: `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` is looking for a true or false return value, so it's possible that if your method returns  too early or raises an exception it might behave unexpectedly. My advice would be to unit test that controller with every possible combination - correct and incorrect password, no password, etc. That way you can be confident that it works as expected. If you're getting something unexpected you should post it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). It's an authentication gem for rails. It's documentation is pretty good.

Comment: I have incorporated devise with my app before, and it didn't work out too well. Could you maybe suggest some videos that would be useful in doing this? I have practically searched the whole internet for api and devise videos lol. Currently for my app I am using api keys, but I find that would be too complicated for the average user trying to access the api

Comment: You should use https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth if you are using api.

Comment: As for video there is not much i can give you. There is one with JWT authentication. But you need to know what is JWT and how to process it.